# How can I delete a file and send it to the recycle bin in Vista/7 using IFileOperation?

Tags: winapi

According to the documentation for [`IFileOperation::SetOperationFlags`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775799.aspx), the `FOFX_RECYCLEONDELETE` flag was introduced in Windows 8.

I would like to delete files and send them to the recycle bin. How is it possible to do that using `IFileOperation` in Vista and Windows 7?

I know that `SHFileOperation` supports that functionality, but I don't want to use `SHFileOperation` as Microsoft are telling us to use `IFileOperation` in its place. Is this possible using `IFileOperation`, and if so, how is it to be done?

Comment: [FOFX_RECYCLEONDELETE: Introduced in Windows 8.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775799.aspx) I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `SetOperationFlags` says:

> This member can be a combination of the following flags. FOF flags are defined in Shellapi.h and FOFX flags are defined in Shobjidl.h.

So you can use the exact same flag, `FOF_ALLOWUNDO`, that you use with `SHFileOperation` to direct a delete action to move to the recycle bin.

Comment: @Remy I suspect that the documentation is flaky. Very hard to see how undo could be implemented on a delete operation without the recycle bin.

Comment: Except that `FOF_ALLOWUNDO` is not documented as involving the Recycle Bin in any way in `IFileOperation`, only in `SHFileOperation`. In fact, for `IFileOperation`, it is documented as NOT storing data in the Recycle Bin at all, but in Explorer.exe instead, so that is why `FOFX_RECYCLEONDELETE` had to be added to regain Recycle Bin behavior.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's actually not what happens. The documentation is imprecise. `FOF_ALLOWUNDO` works just as it always did. Note: I have tested this.  Of course, this all begs the question as to why `FOFX_RECYCLEONDELETE` was introduced.

Comment: I guess if you are performing a series of operations that includes deleting a file, you might want to put the file in the recycle bin but prefer to do so without the overhead of also making all the other operations undoable?  Don't know how often that would come up in practice though.

Comment: @DavidHefferman Do you have any sample code you could paste?  There's not much out there that I could find with Google... the Windows Dev Center example is kinda broken it's missing parameters here and there.

Comment: I think I answered the question you asked. You don't seem to agree.

Answer (score 0):

> FOFX_RECYCLEONDELETE flag was introduced in Win 8 - will it work in Vista/7?

Since `FOFX_RECYCLEONDELETE` was  introduced in Windows 8, then it did not exist in Vista/7, so no, it will not work in those versions.

> There's always SHFileOperation but I'd rather use a more up-to-date Win32 API method. Anything else to know? Any alternate ways of recycling files/folders?

`SHFileOperation()` is the only documented way to recycle files/folders:

> When used to delete a file, SHFileOperation permanently deletes the file unless you set the FOF_ALLOWUNDO flag in the fFlags member of the SHFILEOPSTRUCT structure pointed to by lpFileOp. **Setting that flag sends the file to the Recycle Bin**. If you want to simply delete a file and guarantee that it is not placed in the Recycle Bin, use DeleteFile.

That same flag is available in `IFileOperation`, but its documented behavior is different:

> Preserve undo information, if possible.
>
> **Prior to Windows Vista, operations could be undone only from the same process that performed the original operation**.
>
> In Windows Vista and later systems, the scope of the undo is a user session. Any process running in the user session can undo another operation. **The undo state is held in the Explorer.exe process**, and as long as that process is running, it can coordinate the undo functions.

That is why `FOFX_RECYCLEONDELETE` had to be introduced - to re-add the old Recycle Bin behavior that had been lost when `IFileOperation` was first introduced.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It just seems counter-intuitive for Microsoft to introduce a replacement function with less functionality that the one being replaced i.e. for sending items to the recycle bin which is why I ask.  With IFIleOperation not being able to recycle for Vista and 7...

Comment: @Josh It is counter intuitive, because that's not what happened. `FOF_ALLOWUNDO` works with `IFileOperation` just as it did with `SHFileOperation`.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified David Heffernan's assessment of the FOF_ALLOWUNDO flag's use with IFileOperation to send items to the recycle bin.  Here's the code.  Apparently SHCreateItemFromParsingName is MS's way of saying create an item from a string.  This code is catered to C++ with Qt.  You'll have to initialize COM first of course.

```
void Worker::deleteItem(QString item)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    IFileOperation *pfo;

    wchar_t *itemWChar = new wchar_t[item.length()+1];
    item.toWCharArray(itemWChar);
    itemWChar[item.length()] = 0;
    PCWSTR itemPCWSTR = itemWChar;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOperation,
                          NULL,
                          CLSCTX_ALL,
                          //IID_IFileOperation,
                          IID_PPV_ARGS(&pfo));
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        //error handling here
        return;
    }

    hr = pfo->SetOperationFlags(FOF_ALLOWUNDO | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        //error handling here
        return;
    }

    IShellItem *deleteItem = NULL;
    hr = SHCreateItemFromParsingName(itemPCWSTR,
                                     NULL,
                                     IID_PPV_ARGS(&deleteItem));
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        //error handling here
        return;
    }

    hr = pfo->DeleteItem(deleteItem,NULL);

    if (deleteItem != NULL)
    {
        deleteItem->Release();
    }


    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        //error handling here
        return;
    }

    hr = pfo->PerformOperations();

    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        //error handling here
        return;
    }

    pfo->Release();

    delete[] itemWChar;
}
```